# clarity datagrid and cdkVirtualFor

Tags: angular, clarity

Some time ago if not mistaken Angular released nice feature called virtual scroll
https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

On our project we are using clarity, for displaying bit amount of data clr-datagrid is fine (used with pagination) but if  forcing it to display all data on a single scroll-able page.. well result's not gonna be satisfying..

and I am wondering, is there a way of using *cdkVirtualFor together with clarity data grid. ? 
Or I should stay with *clrDgItems  with pagination?

Comment: were you able to find any solutions yet?

Comment: @KalpeshPatel good question asked on time :) 

No, I did not.. As from today will start working on custome  Vs-scroll component, probably all the styling to match clarity will be pain